# Does Apache Apollo have failover support?

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue, failover, apollo

I'm looking to use a message queue system for an ongoing project, which now is relying on a custom (and brittle) message subsystem to interconnect multiple applications. Both the pub/sub and queue patterns are heavily used in my system.

Apache Apollo is one of the message queue systems I'm taking into account, but I don't find information about how can I handle (for instance) an Apollo server failure. 
Is there a way to provide failover support in Apollo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of now [this has not been resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/APLO-270). Apollo is a very good broker, indeed, but lacks some production critical features like fail over. Apollo was an attempt to make a core for the next generation of ActiveMQ. However, the development is no loger active.

Have you considered other brokers like [Apache Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/)? It's basically a new attempt to remake ActiveMQ with code from HornetQ, ActiveMQ and Apollo. Development is very active at the moment and there is support for fail over etc.

Comment: Yes Apollo is dead, I do not recommend using it. Artemis is the way forward.